# I have problem with tFixedFlowInput and files name in Talend

Tags: talend

i would generate 1 file for each row in my main files

but when my job finished i have the rigth number of files but my file name is indented +1 one compared with the realy code in my file and the first file created is named "null0"

[Screen of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcYHB.png)

[The Job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92pKx.png)

Comment: how are you creating this code operation ? is it something based on the input csv file ? we'll probably need to see code in tMap,tFixedFlow to understand what is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommand using this option in `tFileOutputDelimited`

[image]